# ActionController::UnknownFormat in htmltoword gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using htmltoword gem from here https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword and i just followed the steps from that. but here i get error when i am running my controller

**Error is**

> *ActionController::UnknownFormat in HtmltopdfcController#show*

my controller code is

```
class HtmltopdfcController < ApplicationController
  def show
        respond_to do |format|
        format.docx do
        file = Htmltoword::Document.create params[:docx_html_source], "file_name.docx"
        send_file file.path, :disposition => "attachment"
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Help me out.

Comment: you need to register you mime type, since docx is not available by default. You can check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to

Comment: have you added this `# Add mime-type in /config/initializers/mime_types.rb:
Mime::Type.register "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", :docx`

Comment: already done this. i have followed the exact same thing which are mentioned in that documentation

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?